# Solving a linear second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone explain to me how do we solve this second order linear differential equation ($\kappa = \text{constant}$):

$$\frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2}=\kappa^2 f(x)$$

It is said that general solution is:

$$f(x) = Ae^{\kappa\, x} + Be^{-\kappa\, x}$$

But how do we get it?

Comment: Actually this differential equation is linear.

Comment: do you know about separation of variables?

Comment: But it doesnt have 1st derivative?

Comment: @71GA Saying that a differential equation is linear is not saying that it only involves first order derivatives. It's saying that if you have two (or more) solutions then their addition is also a solution. That's why you need initial conditions to specify which solution is the solution for your (specific) problem, i.e., in the case of your question, specify the constants $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @roger: This is probably better as a comment as opposed to an answer. Regards

Comment: I allways thought that linear diff. eq. was the one which involved third, second and first derivative. I thought that if diff. eq. with only second and first derivative was nonlinear.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this using integration???

Comment: This is a second order, linear, homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients. Corrected the title and text.

Comment: Look at my answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339661/solution-to-the-second-order-differential-equation/1803944#1803944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that our solution is in the form of   $f(x)=e^{c x}$
after you put into first equation  you get

$c^2 e^{c x}-\kappa^2 e^{c x}=0$

If  you take $e^{c x}$ out of bracket, you get

$e^{c x} (c^2-\kappa^2)=0$

or  $c^2=\kappa^2$

Now you should express  $c$ as $\pm\kappa$ and insert into first equation,
and of course multiply  each  variant by  some constant  $A_1$, $A_2$  and add.

Comment: @71GA   could  you  read this  solution? i mean symbols

Comment: I am not quite sure where your first equation originates from. Did you use $k$ instead of $\kappa$?